# How recursive function is returning value?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function reverse(str){
    if(str.length <= 1) {
        return str;
    } 
    return reverse(str.slice(1)) + str[0];
}

console.log(reverse("two"))
```

When the last `return str` line hits inside the `if` statement, it returns `'o'`. Yet there is an extra  `+ str[0]` outside the `if` statement. Shouldn't it be returning `'oo'` rather than `'o'`?

The function is working completely fine, but when I try to visualize it I get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it happens in order of the function's internal behavior:

1. `reverse('two')` is called
2. `reverse('two')` calls `reverse(str.slice(1))` which evaluates to a call to `reverse('wo')`
3. `reverse('wo')` calls `reverse(str.slice(1))` which evaluates to a call to `reverse('o')`
4. `if(str.length <= 1)` evaluates to *true* and the the `reverse('o')` call returns `'o'` to the caller
5. The `reverse('wo')` call returns `'ow'` to the caller (`str[0]` was `'w'`)
6. The `reverse('two')` call returns `'owt'` to the caller (`str[0]` was `'t'`)

and the final result is `'owt'`, as expected.

So in

```
return reverse(str.slice(1)) + str[0];
```

`str[0]` will not be added to `reverse(str.slice(1))` until the function call returns. and when it returns the value of `str[0]` will be the value it was when `reverse(str.slice(1))` was called.

When the `if` statement is satisfied and evaluates to *true* it exits the current function call immediately returning the value `'o'` to the caller, since there is a return statement inside the *if*.

```
if(str.length <= 1) {
    return str;       // <-- exits here and returns 'o'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A visual representation of the code.
[image]

Comment: thank you for such a beautiful representation... best explanation ever.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

It will enter the `if` branch only when the string length is less than or equal to 1

eg. str = "o"

then it will enter

```
if(str.length <= 1) {
    return str; //here your function will return the answer to main() and will exit this function
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
o
```

Since you are writing `return str` it will immediately return from that function and will not execute any following lines of code. So it will **not** execute this:

```
return reverse(str.slice(1)) + str[0]; //this part will never be reached
```

The  above part will be executed only if the `str len>=2`

---

Let us now understand the recursion stack

```
str  =  "two"
```

This is how recursion works--

```
reverse(two) = reverse(wo)+ t = reverse(o)+ wt = o+wt = owt
```

**Note :** `reverse(o)` will simply return `o` as length of string is 1